# Draw round corner image ios

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have a button that is custom drawn using Core Graphics, and I want to change it so it is drawn with rounded corners and with white stroke round borders. I'm also setting a background image.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController,
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if  let  pickedImage  = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        myButton.layer.cornerRadius =  // Nothing Give me here circle
        myButton.clipsToBounds = true
        myButton.layer.borderWidth = 12.0
        myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        myButton.setBackgroundImage(pickedImage, forState: .Normal)
        myButton.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

This is what I get when I apply `myButton.layer.cornerRadius = myButtonrect.size.height/2`

[image]

Comment: I believe you also need to mask layer: `myButton.layer.masksToBounds = true;`

Comment: @rokjarc `clipsToBounds` & `masksToBounds` are one and same property. `clipsToBounds` is just a forwarded version of the layer's `masksToBounds`, purely for convenience.

Comment: What is the frame of the button? What are you getting? What do you expect?

Comment: it is a rectangle , I am getting diamond shape when myButton.layer.cornerRadius = myButton.size.height/2  ,  I expect a Circle

Comment: @jassimabdrhman It's completely impossible to create a circle by adding a corner radius to a rectangle. Are you looking to create an ellipse or a circle within an aspect fitted square?

Comment: You will not get a circle when adding a corner radius to a rectangle. If you would like a circle you can set your button to be a square.

Comment: Thanks it work.              Mybutton.frame.size.width = Mybutton.frame.size.height